# Exporting Custom List view in Sharepoint 2010 to Excel

Tags: 2010, excel, export

I am creating a custom list view programatically which hides some of the columns in the actual list. But while exporting to excel all the columns are visible. Any tips/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CSOM approach you can remove the fields from the `ViewFieldCollection`. This will help you to keep the required columns in the export.

Eg:

```
ViewFieldCollection viewFields = view.ViewFields;
viewFields.Remove("LinkFilename");
```